# Проблема с парсингом использую jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Сразу вырожу благодарность за предыдущий ответ. При парсинге данные отображаются как нужно. Но при переходе по ссылке выводит ошибку, пытался прикрепить к ссылке заголовка доменное имя `http://ktits.ru`, тогда выводит просто пустое окно. Так же пытался выводить log.i, результатов не дало.
Поток для работы с jsoup оставил в главной активности, не выносил в отдельный ява класс. Данные с сайта помещаю в массив через map.put.
Вот код всей активности:
Логи:[image: logs]
HTML код сайта:[image: HTML]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textView;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
    parseTitle.execute();
    try {
        final HashMap<String,String> hashMap = parseTitle.get();
        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet()){
            arrayList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ParseText parseText = new ParseText();
                parseText.execute(hashMap.get(arrayList.get(position)));
                try {
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setText(parseText.get());
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


class ParseText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String str = "";

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div[class=text]").get(0).getElementsByTag("p");
           // Log.i(str,"fgds");
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;

    }
}


 class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String,String>>
```

{

```
 @Override
 protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
     HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
     try {
         Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://ktits.ru").get();
         Elements elements = document.select("div[class=news]").get(0).getElementsByTag("a");
         for(Element element:elements) {
             hashMap.put(element.getElementsByClass("title").text(), element.attr("href"));
        }

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return hashMap;
 }
```

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно делали, когда прикрепляли `http://ktits.ru` ссылку к строке. А пустое окно выводит из-за того что вы не присвоили значение локально переменной `str` в своем методе.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String str = "";

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div[class=text]").get(0).getElementsByTag("p");
            str = elements.first().ownText(); <-- вот
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;

    }
```

**UPD**:
А что бы избежать волокиты с прикреплением строки в классе `ParseTitle` берите не сам атрибут `href`, а его абсолютный `url`.
С этого

```
 hashMap.put(element.getElementsByClass("title").text(), element.attr("href"));
```

на это

```
 hashMap.put(element.getElementsByClass("title").text(), element.absUrl("href"));
```

Comment: Мне казалось что он будет брать только то что записано в контейнере... Видимо нужно мат часть по jsoup пересмотреть. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: Я рекомендую "щупать" всё в дебагере быстро и наглядно получается, сам так работаю, когда не понятно.